# Why this pangram program is not giving correct anwer?

Tags: c

Please help me to find the error in this code.
And also tell me how to remove a specific character (e.x. a space) from an array of characters/string.
If the input string is 
" We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize "
Then how to make an array of characters on which I have to work like this 
" Wepromptlyjudgedantiqueivorybucklesforthenextprize "

Thank You!!

```
int a[26] = {0};
int c = 0;
char* str = (char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", str);

for( int i = 0; str[i]!= '\0' && str[i]!= ' ' ; i++) {
if( str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A') {
    a[0]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'b' || str[i] == 'B') {
    a[1]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'c' || str[i] == 'C') {
    a[2]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'd' || str[i] == 'D') {
    a[3]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'E') {
    a[4]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'f' || str[i] == 'F') {
    a[5]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'g' || str[i] == 'G') {
    a[6]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'h' || str[i] == 'H') {
    a[7]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'I') {
    a[8]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'j' || str[i] == 'J') {
    a[9]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'K' || str[i] == 'k') {
    a[10]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'l' || str[i] == 'L') {
    a[11]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'm' || str[i] == 'M') {
    a[12]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'n' || str[i] == 'N') {
    a[13]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'O') {
    a[14]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'p' || str[i] == 'P') {
    a[15]++;

};

if( str[i] == 'q' || str[i] == 'Q') {
    a[16]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'r' || str[i] == 'R') {
    a[17]++;

};
if( str[i] == 's' || str[i] == 'S') {
    a[18]++;

};
if( str[i] == 't' || str[i] == 'T') {
    a[19]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'U') {
    a[20]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'v' || str[i] == 'V') {
    a[21]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'w' || str[i] == 'W') {
    a[22]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'x' || str[i] == 'X') {
    a[23]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'y' || str[i] == 'Y') {
    a[24]++;

};
if( str[i] == 'z' || str[i] == 'Z') {
    a[25]++;

};
};
for( int a0 = 0; a0 < 26; a0++) {
if( a[a0] > 0 ) c++;
};
if( c == 26 ) printf("pangram");
else printf("not pangram");
```

Comment: Remove the 26 icky if statements and replace them with `if ( isalpha(str[i]) ){ size_t index = toupper(str[i]) - 'A'; a[index]++; }`

Comment: Also replace the loop with `if( a[a0] > 0 ) c++;` with `bool pangram = true; for(int i=0; i<26; i++) { if(a[i] == 0){ pangram=false; break} }`

Comment: *Remove the 26 icky if statements and replace them with if ( isalpha(str[i]) ){ size_t index = toupper(str[i]) - 'A'; a[index]++; }*  No.  Do not do this.  Alphabetic characters are not guaranteed to be represented contiguously.  `'Z' - 'A'` is not guaranteed to be 25.  The **5.2.1 Charater Sets** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) merely guarantees the numeric characters 0-9 are contiguous.

Comment: @user3121023 `scanf ( "%s"` skips white-spaces and _then_ will stop at first whitespace (after scanning non-white-space)  Recommending `fgets()` is still a good idea.

Comment: @Lundin *Yes absolutely do this. If you are some token table fetishist you can add something like #ifdef EBCDIC #error Your system is crap. #endif or #if 'Z' - 'A' != 0 #error Your system is crap #endif. If you suspect your token table to be designed by people who lack common sense, add static assertions.*  So the C Standard committee "lack[s] common sense"?  Should we assume that indicates the weight one should give to your comments?

Comment: In addition of what has been said, you should indent your program properly for your own sake.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, it looks to me like you are trying to be more catholic than the pope. Sure, there is no guarantee for A-Z being sequential in the standard, but realistically, there is not a single implementation that isn't so, and there will never be.

Comment: @Aganju *it looks to me like you are trying to be more catholic than the pope. Sure, there is no guarantee for A-Z being sequential in the standard, but realistically, there is not a single implementation that isn't so, and there will never be.*  [Oh?  Are you sure?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)  But if you want to make unsupportable assumptions when you code, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Read the input with `fgets()` as that will read a *line* of input.  `scanf("%s", str);` will only save `"We"` with input like `" We promptly ..."`.

```
if (fgetc(str, 1000, stdin)) {
  // drop test for ' '
  // for( int i = 0; str[i]!= '\0' && str[i]!= ' ' ; i++) {
  for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
    ....
  }

  // To only print letters
  for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
    if (isalpha(str[i]) fputc(str[i], stdout);
  }
  fputc('\n', stdout);
```

---

On a separate issue: the repeated 26 tests certainly can be simplified.

```
#include <ctype.h>

if (isalpha((unsigned char) str[i])) {
  size_t index = toupper((unsigned char) str[i]) - 'A';
  a[index]++;
}
```

Or portably with

```
#include <ctype.h>

const char AZ[]= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char *p = strchr(AZ, toupper((unsigned char) str[i]));
if (p && *p) {
  a[p-AZ]++;
}
```

or various other schemes.

Answer (score 0):

1. scanf with "%s" does stop reading at the first blank. As you don't need formatted reading anyway, use fgets() instead (or change the format code to something that *allows* blanks, like "%[^\n]", which stops only at a return)
2. Because of the condition in the for loop, it ends at the first blank. You should test for the blank inside the loop and bypass processing it, but still keep the loop running - the way you coded it, the whole loop ends when it is found.

Comment: "scanf with "%s" does stop reading at the first blank." is not so.  [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436609/why-this-pangram-program-is-not-giving-correct-anwer/34437034#comment56614416_34436609).